# How can I scan through the list of string array items to identify which part matches regex expression for url and convert it to link w react typescri

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

IMessage is an interface with type string. The app is something like a todo list, but I need it to identify when a URL is typed in and convert it to a clickable link

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState<IMessage[]>([]);
  const regex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;

  useEffect(() => {
    chat.forEach(chat => {
      ///function 
    })
    })
```

here's a bigger piece of code that I have at the moment

````
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState<IMessage[]>([]);
  const regex = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;

  
  const sendMessage = () => {
    const newMessage = { message: message };
    setChat([...chat, newMessage]);
    setMessage("");
  };

  const inputChanged = (
    event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => setMessage(event.target.value);

  return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Stack
          direction="column"
          spacing={2}
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="flex-end"
        >
          {chat.map((message: IMessage) => {
            return (
              <Paper
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#6096ba",
                  padding: "5px",
                  borderRadius: "30px",
                }}
                elevation={3}
              >
                <p style={{ maxWidth: "20ch", color: "white" }}>
                  {message.message}
                </p>
              </Paper>
            );
          })}
        </Stack>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use it.includes() if I got you right, Then you add whatever you want to do with it.
-Another tip: Create your function out of useEffect then  just call it inside the effect, you might have a big project then you will find it harder and not useful at all

Comment: .includes() is not accepting regex expression, though I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way

Comment: Sure , try .match() 
It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `useEffect` for this if you want it to change the rendering to be a link.

Your return would look something like the following. You would choose to either render as plain text or as a link.

```
return (
  <ol>
    {chat.map((chatMessage) => {
      return chatMessage.match(regex) ? (
        <li>
          <a href={chatMessage}>{chatMessage}</a>
        </li>
      ) : (
        <li>{chatMessage}</li>
      );
    })}
  </ol>
);
```

Comment: I was trying that earlier, but my interface with type string is not working with match() function either. It's first time using typescript and interface to define the array type, so I'm still very confused with what I'm doing in general

Comment: Do you have a more complete example? In this playground, an array of strings has the match function.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBDKAuG0BOBLMBzA2gLowC8M+A5FlAKYC2MAjBQDQxW0MBMr78UUAA4QUAelHREwANYgAbjQwAzADYgA7gDpQdCoQDcAKFCRYGGrhoAPUjFH8hEAPwoAOqPcAKdT9eaAlE74ALSIwQBeAILBAFoADMEAnAACKACkmgD6rgDUAH4AxCSEAN6MLFwArABsAL5++GFRsQmJnv6l5XWuAEaeIU3R8UntqWnZOZqFTgBk4sUAVP6iRsZIUJp0iIKensD+pAB8MCWGMOdw4BAgKjSaarh7m8gInuaWVgdOMAAGACQlYC1GBYCAwRAwFQ4aQ-GBof6A4GgmBgECwCFQsAw-xGWr+QxAA

Comment: this is what the interface looks like:
''' 
export interface IMessage{
    message: string;
   
}
'''
and when I try to use match with it, I get the "Property 'match' does not exist on type 'IMessage'"
I believe that the definition of the interface is incorrect but I'm struggling to find how to fix it

Comment: Ah, there's a `message` property in there. See this new [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkIGctwOYQDeyAttrgQFzJZhSh4DcyAvowFAID2ItyCACzhhqGcvggBtALrIAvMknEyOCdQDkwSCWQBGdawA0yZeKrJkm7cgBMBlsdOrz6gWDAAHLJQD0P2ogA1lwAbtAwADZcAO4AdNwk9tIc3LxgyFAQBAAe8sg+bp5YAPyUADo+FQAU0bVlsQCUxZIAtHAtAF4Agi0AWgAMLQCcAAKUAKSxAPplANQAfgDEctKEuoY2AKwAbCz1ku3dfYNDVQ2r67tlAEZVrYc9A8NnY+Mzs7FLxQBkfisAVA0fBxOEIwLESHAPFUqggGvIAHwmdgWCypLBcCIQWJRPCwiFmbGQsCCKqZHLw4rIAAGABJCAgWMhgFhkHBkBFQIFqchqHSGUyWcgQFx0uzOSBuQ0OCwGuwgA). You need to use `chat.message.match` in your case.

Comment: it makes sense to me, but it's giving out the same error

Comment: Can you share a more complete picture of your code? Or can you see where the playground is different from your code?

Comment: I attached more code above. I tried adding the match() function in the return, following the chat.message.match(), but it highlights the message part with the same error

Comment: Where you currently have `{message.message}`, it rejects `{message.message.match(regex)}`?

Comment: you are right! I was using it in the wrong place. I have another question, I'm trying to upload the project to git now but it's giving me an error of "Error: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator  react/jsx-key "  on those lines, any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: Because you're iterating to create a set of React elements, each of those elements needs a `key` property. In your case specifically, that's the `<Paper />` element. It needs something like `<Paper key={message.message} ... />`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html